# NGRX/RXJS observer not emitting on page refresh

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have a component that allows a user to edit an entry.  If the user arrives to the edit page from the previous component (table) my observer is able to select the user from the Store and populate the fields with the correct data.

If I refresh the page however, the observer does keep returning null.  What's odd is the nGif on the edit form fills out the correct label from the user.  That tells me that the Observable object isn't null since nGif wouldn't render the labels.  The observer who's subscribed to it seems to be the problem.

Form:

```
<form id="editContainer" [formGroup]="editForm" *ngIf="userObjectUnderEdit | async as userEdit">
        <div class="form-group">
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
            <mat-label>{{userEdit.name}}</mat-label>
            <input class="formInput" matInput placeholder="{{userEdit.name}}" formControlName="name" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                <mat-label>{{userEdit.email}}</mat-label>
                <input class="formInput" resizeToFitContent="true" matInput placeholder="{{userEdit.email}}" formControlName="email" required>
              </mat-form-field>
        </div>
...
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('in ngoninit');
    this.editBuildForm();
    this.loaduserForEdit();
    
    // this.setEditFormValues();
  }

  loadUserForEdit() {
    const routeSubscription = this.store.select(getCurrentRouteState).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(route => {
        const userId = route.params.userId;
        console.log("route params id: ", userId);
        this.store.dispatch(loadEditeduser({userId}));
        this.store.dispatch(setEditeduserId({userId}));
    });
    this.userObjectUnderEdit = this.store.select(getCurrentuser);
    const userFillSubscriber = this.userObjectUnderEdit.subscribe(user => this.userFormFill = user);
    this.setEditFormValues(this.userFormFill);
    userFillSubscriber.unsubscribe();
    routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

const userFillSubscriber = this.userObjectUnderEdit.subscribe(user => this.userFormFill = user);
^ user is null whenever page is refreshed.
However, the ngIf still populates the mat-labels so userObjectUnderEdit is still working correctly.

Comment: Can you share the state at the moment of reloading the page? And the getCurrentUser selector?

Comment: State does not persist on browser refresh and I instead perform a GET operation to retrieve just that user based on route params.

Comment: I meant the moment the ngOnInit is called. But I see your problem is solved! Good luck further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    const userFillSubscriber = this.userObjectUnderEdit.subscribe(user => this.userFormFill = user);
    this.setEditFormValues(this.userFormFill);
```

You are setting the property `userFormFill` inside the subscribe block and then running

```
 this.setEditFormValues(this.userFormFill);
```

I'm going to borrow T. van den Berg's code but modify it slightly:

```
const userFillSubscriber = this.userObjectUnderEdit.pipe(
    filter(user => !!user), 
    take(1)
).subscribe(user => {
    this.userFormFill = user;
    this.setEditFormValues(this.userFormFill) // add this line inside your subscribe as well
});
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you and T. van den Berg for the assistance.  I feel like I tried every combination except for that!  In the future I'll be more careful to put whatever method call relies on the emitted value inside the block that defines the value.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a race condition issue. The userFillSubscriber gets unsubscribed possibly before the subscription emits anything else then null. Usually you only unsubscribe when the component breaks down (onDestroy). Or you limit the emissions by take(x).

Maybe this will help:

```
const userFillSubscriber = this.userObjectUnderEdit
.pipe(filter(user => !!user), take(1))
.subscribe(user => 
this.userFormFill = user);
```

Both the .unsubscribe functions are unnecessary then. The subscription stop after 1 emission because if the take(1) operator.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I've tried it with the take(1) operator and I still get the undefined error.  I also got rid of my unsubscribe line and still the same results.